# Is Farady's law valid for conducting loop only?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Is it applicable to a nonconductive loop? What if the loop consists of both non-conducting and conducting paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faraday's law is for a mathematical loop, even with nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Faradays law for any loop as long as it is complete